# Eclipse: How can I add a library?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

it sounds probably really dumb, but how can I add a library to Eclipse? 
I'm trying this one, but I have no idea how to do it: http://code.google.com/p/streamscraper/

I tried alot of things now, but none of them worked out.

EDIT: This is the zip : http://streamscraper.googlecode.com/archive/f01d9ac6462902f0d2e7f6dc15cbef623ebe99f3.zip

EDIT2: It is a folder with classes

Comment: is it a jar file or a library project like google play services library project?

Comment: It is just a folder with classes

Comment: is it  a library project if so http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html. if its a jar add it to your build path as jon skeet suggested

Comment: pash, please edit information like "it is just a folder with classes" to your question as well, as it may influence the answers given.

Comment: Oh, it's not a folder with just classes (most of the time, people use this phrase for a folder containing `.class` files, not one that contains `.java` files), it is an Eclipse project which you should import. Given the status (unknown) it is probably better to refer directly to the imported project in the build configuration as Jon suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way, assuming it's a jar file:

- Make sure the jar file is in your project directory (so it should show up in package explorer)
- Right-click the project root
- Choose "Build path" / "Configure build path..."
- Go to the "Libraries" tab
- Click "Add JARs"
- Navigate to the jar file and click OK

Or without even having it in your project directory, you can right-click on the project root, select "Build path" / "Add External Archives..." and find the file wherever it is. Personally I like having the jar file within the project directory though.

EDIT: It looks like you've actually got an Eclipse project there, basically. So extract the zip file, add the project to Eclipse (File / Import / General / Existing projects into workspace) and then make your project depend on that project via the build path.

By the looks of it, the zip file has some dependencies missing - you probably want to consult the project home page for any instructions on getting it building right.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not a jar file. Just a folder with classes.

Comment: It worked! I created a new project and exported it as a jar file. Thx!